# Automating taking screenshots of a website

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been given the horrible task of doing this.

- Launch the website
- Take a screenshot
- Fill in the form details, click on Next
- Take a screenshot
- ...
- ...
- ...

Rinse. Repeat.

Now, with various combinations, this comes up to 300 screenshots.

And I have to do this for 4 different browsers. Chrome, Firefox, IE 6 and IE 7.

I cannot use tools which will capture the screenshot and store them, such as, SnagIT. I need to take a screenshot, copy it to a Word Document and take the second screenshot and take it to a Word Document.

I thought, I will write a tiny utility which will help me do this. Here is the requirement spec that I put up for it -

1. An executable which once launched seats itself in the System Tray.
2. While it is active, all instances of Key Press (Print Scrn), it should write the contents to a Word Document as defined (either a default path or a user defined one).
3. Save the document periodically.

Now, my question is - if I am going to develop this using C# (Winforms application), how do I go about doing this.

I can do a fair bit of C# programming and I am willing to learn. But I am not able to locate the references for how to do a background process so that it runs in the background. And while it runs, it has to capture the Print Scrn command.

Can you folks point me to the right material where I can learn this? Theoretical references should suffice. But if there are practical references, then nothing like it.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question for http://stackoverflow.com . I'm not sure how to migrate from here to SO, so you might want to just re-ask the question over there. This one's probably going to get closed.

Comment: I think that the title is wrong for this post.

Comment: Oh, never mind, there's a mechanism to vote to have it moved. You should probably go ahead and make an account on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

WatiN has screenshot methods and will work for firefox. Selenium is probably better suited however as it supports more browsers.

However I would recommend that if you can, leverage something like browsershots.org to get the screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

As recently answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214474/simulate-user-input-in-3rd-party-application/5214572#5214572), you could try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It's not browser-based, but there's no reason why it has to be, and all the heavy-lifting has already been done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from what are you are looking for but worth a shot.

For automation of website testing, have a look at [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/index.html) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). As for capturing the screenshot, have a look at this - http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Capturing_the_image_of_the_screen_using_C.aspx . For saving the image to a Word document you can use Office Automation. Now link all this together and you have got your tool. :)

Best of luck. Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this with both Cucumber and Capybara, but the Cucumber way is much easier. First, under your project file, create two folders: (1) failed_png and (2) success_png. Then, in your env.rb file, paste the following code:

```
After do |scenario|
  take_screenshot(@browser, scenario)
end

def take_screenshot(browser, scenario)
  if scenario.failed?
    scenario_name = scenario.name.gsub /[^\w\-]/, ' '
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M")
    screenshot_path = './failed_png/' + time + ' - ' + scenario_name + '.png'
  else
    scenario_name = scenario.name.gsub /[^\w\-]/, ' '
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M")
    screenshot_path = './success_png/' + time + ' - ' + scenario_name + '.png'
  end
  browser.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
end
```

This takes a screen shot after each scenario and places it either in the SUCCESS folder or FAILED folder accordingly with the time stamp on it.

For a complete env.rb file and more documentation, see my blog at whitneytaylorimura.wordpress.com